# TableView cells do not communicate with their DetailView.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a TableViewController called `SecondViewController`. The cells' name is ok and everything works fine, but when it comes to loading the detailed view, which in my case is called `ArticleViewController`, it does not want to communicate with the detailed view's properties. So basically, if I want to change a label in the detailed view, it just does not work.

Here is the code:

**SecondViewController.h**

```
@interface SecondViewController : UITableViewController 
{
    NSMutableArray *json;
}

@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ArticleViewController *article = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ArticleViewController"];
    NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@",[info objectForKey:@"username"]);
    [article.usernameLabel setText:[info objectForKey:@"username"]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:article animated:YES];


}
```

**ArticleViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ArticleViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *usernameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *articleTitle;

@end
```

**ArticleViewController.m**

--synthesizing properties--

I hooked the labels and the ArticleViewController up, but the label never changes.

Comment: Don't save information in UI variables. Create special vars for name and article and load when they are need (e.g. viewWillAppear:)

Comment: Thank you very much ! This worked :). I just wonder why... But THANK YOU !!

Comment: It's too important 4 you to understand why - Read more about loading view, about lazy initialization, etc.
If talk a short view outlets will be created much later then your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the `article` hadn't loaded its nib by the time you did `article.usernameLabel setText:`.  So `article.usernameLabel` was still `nil`.  You could force `article` to load its nib by doing `[article view]`.  But OdNairy's advice is better.